# Como desplazar de posición una cadena en una estructura en C?

Tags: array, c, string, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy aplicando el concepto de cola en un programa, el programa puede registrar datos, mostrarlos y eliminarlos.
Esta es la estructura que utilizo:

```
struct personal {
  char nombre [40];
  char apellido [40]; 
  int  edad; 
  float  sueldo; 
}  ;

    int j,i =0; //indices
    int opc=0;
    char k [3];
    personal cliente [100];
```

Mi problema es al momento de eliminar los datos, quiero eliminar los datos de la posición inicial (0) y luego desplazar hacia atrás los datos restantes :

```
void elimina(){
    do{     
        system("cls");
        printf("\n EL CLIENTE A ELIMINAR ES :  \n ");
        printf("\n nombre  : %s \n ",cliente[0].nombre );
        printf("\n apellido: %s \n ",cliente[0].apellido );
        printf("\n edad    : %d \n ",cliente[0].edad ); 
        printf("\n sueldo  : %f \n ",cliente[0].sueldo );
        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            cliente[j].nombre= cliente[j+1].nombre; //Intento fallido
            cliente[j].apellido= cliente[j+1].apellido; //Intento fallido
            cliente[j].edad = cliente[j+1].edad;
            cliente[j].sueldo = cliente[j+1].sueldo ;
        }
        



        printf("\n Desea elimnar otro cliente: [si=1/no=2] \n");
        scanf("%d" ,&opc);
        i--;
        getch();
    }while (opc==1 && i>0);
    
    

}
```

La variable `cliente[j].edad` y `cliente[j].sueldo` se desplazan correctamente, mi problema es con las variables tipo cadena, no se como desplazarlas. Ahí hice un intento, pero no me sale correctamente.

Comment: Según tu implementación de la función `strncpy`: rellenas con '\0' una cantidad de caracteres igual a `sizeof(cliente[j+1].nombre]`en la posición anterior (j). ¿No sería más lógico hacer `strncpy(cliente[j].nombre, cliente[j+1].nombre, sizeof(cliente[j+1].nombre))`? Y lo mismo para el apellido. Por otro lado, el índice `i` está inicializado como '0' y luego lo decrementas dentro de la misma función (¿Tiene en realidad eso sentido?).

Comment: @Londo Gracias por tu comentario, esa fue la solución.

Comment: Con respecto al indice, se decrementa para poder eliminar siempre el inicio del arreglo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay formas mucho mas simples de hacerlo. Puesto que estás usando una `struct`, el tamaño de tus datos es conocido y fijo. Por lo tanto, podemos usar perfectamente la función [`memcpy( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) (en la cabecera `<string.h>`). Esta función nos permite mover **toda una instancia** de `personal`, sin necesidad de ir copiando miembro a miembro:

```
void elimina( ) {
    do{     
        system("cls");
        printf("\n EL CLIENTE A ELIMINAR ES :  \n ");
        printf("\n nombre  : %s \n ",cliente[0].nombre );
        printf("\n apellido: %s \n ",cliente[0].apellido );
        printf("\n edad    : %d \n ",cliente[0].edad ); 
        printf("\n sueldo  : %f \n ",cliente[0].sueldo );
        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            memcpy( &( cliente[j] ), &( cliente[j + 1] ), sizeof( struct personal ) );
        }

        printf("\n Desea elimnar otro cliente: [si=1/no=2] \n");
        scanf("%d" ,&opc);
        i--;
        getch();
    }while (opc==1 && i>0);
}
```

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias, de esa forma se optimiza mucho más el código. Estudiaré mas a fondo las funciones de string.h